# navigate is not a function to moving screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React MNavigation5 for navigating to screen but I encounter an error:

> `navigate is not a function`:

```
function Categories() {

   const navigate = useNavigation();

   function navigateToScreen() {
      navigate('ApartmentSales');
   }

   return (
     <View >
        <Text style={Styles.TextCategories}>دسته بندی ها</Text>
        {/* ---------------------------------------------------------------لایه کلی صفحه---------------------------------- */}
        <View style={Styles.View}>
            {/* --------------------------------------------------------------- لایه دکمه ها---------------------------------- */}
            <Button style={Styles.Button} onPress={ () => navigateToScreen}>
                <MaterialIcons name="waves" size={30} color={"#0c7656"} />
                <Text style={Styles.Text}>زمین</Text>

            </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call the function.

Instead of:

```js
onPress={() => navigateToScreen}
```

Do:

```js
onPress={() => navigateToScreen()}
```

Or:

```js
onPress={navigateToScreen}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

function navigateToScreen() {
    navigation.navigate('ApartmentSales');
}
```